# Select option from dropdown using protractor wont dismiss my dropdown

Tags: css, google-chrome, jasmine, protractor

Still new to Protractor, Jasmine etc.

Today, I am trying to interact with a dropdown options list in one of my tests.

here it is:

var selectDropDown = element(by.css('.dropdown'));
    allOptions = element.all(by.options('Some Options'));

Clicking on the drop down now

selectDropDown.click();

Clicking on the Option in the dropdown with index 2

allOptions.get(2).click();

Some Code for assertion....

Now the issue is that it reaches the element on Index 2, i am sure of this coz I did the getText() on the element get(2).

But, when I am calling the click statement, it seems to click( i suppose) but the dropdown would never dismiss resulting in my assertions failing.

I am using the Chrome Browser for running my tests.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
element(by.css('.dropdown')).$('[value="Value of Your Option"]').click();
```

In this by using `element(by.css('.dropdown'))` we can get the total drop down List. Here .dropdown is not a static, it is customised Locator.
    **$** **is a css selector**, from this we can select the element by using Locator Value or what ever.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 1):

Do not click the drop down first.  Just directly reach to your option using `cssContainingText`